# How to filter List of params with Criteria Builder?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have filter feature in my Spring Boot application, and everything is working perfect except when I need to filter list of items. Those items are called "tags" in my application.
When I insert just one tag in URL like this

```
http://localhost:8080/mybrocki/ads/filter?tag=Antique
```

Ecerything is okay. But when I insert few more tags like:

```
http://localhost:8080/mybrocki/ads/filter?tag=Antique&tag=Malfunction
```

I am always getting empty array(it shouldn't be). This is my controller

```
@GetMapping("/ads/filter")
    public ResponseEntity<List<AdsDTO>> getAdsByParam(@RequestParam(required = false) String region,
                                                        @RequestParam(required = false) AdsSubGroup adssubgroup,
                                                        @RequestParam(required = false) Long userId,
                                                        @RequestParam(required = false) String status,
                                                        @RequestParam(required = false) String businessType,
                                                        @RequestParam(required = false) String adsType,
                                                        @RequestParam(required = false) Long adsGroupId,
                                                        @RequestParam(required = false) Integer fromPrice,
                                                        @RequestParam(required = false) Integer toPrice,
                                                        @RequestParam(required = false) Boolean fixedPrice,
                                                        @RequestParam(required = false) Boolean freeDelivery,
                                                        @RequestParam(required = false) Boolean productWarranty,
                                                        @RequestParam(required = false) Boolean urgentSales,
                                                        @RequestParam(required = false)Boolean hasImage,
                                                        @RequestParam(required = false) Integer pageNumber,
                                                        @RequestParam(required = false) Integer pageSize,
                                                        @RequestParam(required = false, value = "tag") List<String> tags) throws ForbiddenException {
        return new ResponseEntity<List<AdsDTO>>(adsServiceImplement.findAll(adssubgroup, userId, status, adsType, businessType, adsGroupId, region, fromPrice, toPrice, fixedPrice, freeDelivery, productWarranty, urgentSales, hasImage, pageNumber, pageSize, tags), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

And this is my method for filtering:

```
 @Override
        public List<AdsDTO> findAll(AdsSubGroup adssubgroup, Long userId, String status, String adsType, 
                                    String businessType, Long adsGroupId, String region, Integer fromPrice, 
                                    Integer toPrice, Boolean fixedPrice, Boolean freeDelivery, Boolean productWarranty, 
                                    Boolean urgentSales, Boolean hasImage, Integer pageNumber, Integer pageSize, List<String> tags) {

         CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
         CriteriaQuery<Ads> query = builder.createQuery(Ads.class);
         Root<Ads> ads = query.from(Ads.class);
         query.orderBy(builder.desc(ads.get("adsDate")));
         List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
         Join<Ads, JwtUser> adsUsersJoin = ads.join("users");
         Join<Ads, AdsSubGroup> adsAdsSubGroupJoin = ads.join("adssubgroup");
         Join<Ads, Tag> tagsJoin = ads.join("adsTags");

         if (!Objects.isNull(adsGroupId)) {
             predicates.add(builder.equal(adsAdsSubGroupJoin.get("adsGroupId"), adsGroupId));
         }
         if (!Objects.isNull(adssubgroup)) {
             predicates.add(builder.equal(ads.get("adssubgroup"),adssubgroup));
         }

         if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(region)) {
             predicates.add(builder.like(adsUsersJoin.get("region"), region));
         }

         if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(businessType)) {
             predicates.add(builder.equal(adsUsersJoin.get("businessType"), businessType ));
         }
         
         if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(status)) {
             
             predicates.add(builder.equal(ads.get("status"), status));
         }
         
         if (!Objects.isNull(userId)) {
             
             predicates.add(builder.equal(ads.get("userId"), userId));
         }

         if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(adsType)) {
             predicates.add(builder.equal(ads.get("adsType"), adsType));
         }

         if (!Objects.isNull(fromPrice) && !Objects.isNull(toPrice) && fromPrice < toPrice) {
                predicates.add(builder.between(ads.get("price"), fromPrice, toPrice));
            }

         if (!Objects.isNull(fixedPrice)) {
             if (fixedPrice) {
             predicates.add(builder.equal(ads.get("fixedPrice"), true));
             } else {
             predicates.add(builder.equal(ads.get("fixedPrice"), false));
             }
         }

         if (!Objects.isNull(freeDelivery)) {
             if (freeDelivery) {
             predicates.add(builder.equal(ads.get("freeDelivery"), true));
             } else {
             predicates.add(builder.equal(ads.get("freeDelivery"), false));
             }
         }

         if (!Objects.isNull(productWarranty)) {
             if (productWarranty) {
             predicates.add(builder.equal(ads.get("productWarranty"), true));
             } else {
             predicates.add(builder.equal(ads.get("productWarranty"), false));
             }
         }

         if (!Objects.isNull(urgentSales)) {
             if (urgentSales) {
             predicates.add(builder.equal(ads.get("urgentSales"), true));
             } else {
             predicates.add(builder.equal(ads.get("urgentSales"), false));
             }
         }

         if (!Objects.isNull(hasImage)) {
             if (hasImage) {
                 predicates.add(builder.isNotNull(ads.get("image")));
             } else {
                 predicates.add(builder.isNull(ads.get("image")));
             }
         }
         
            
              if (tags != null && tags.size() > 0) { 
                  for (String tag : tags) {
                  predicates.add(builder.equal(tagsJoin.get("name"), tag));
                  }
              }
              query.select(ads);
         query.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
         if(!(pageNumber==null && pageSize==null)) {
             TypedQuery<Ads> typedQuery = em.createQuery(query);
             typedQuery.setFirstResult((pageNumber-1)*pageSize);
             typedQuery.setMaxResults(pageSize);
             List<Ads> adsList = typedQuery.getResultList();
             return AdsConverter.convertToAdsDTO(adsList);
         }else {
             List<Ads> adsList = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
             return AdsConverter.convertToAdsDTO(adsList);
         }
 
     }
```

Can someone tells me where I am wrong?

Comment: As a side note - you know you can use an object as the controller parameter and request params will map to the properties?

Comment: Yes I know, but as I said from that side everything is okay, something in query is not okay...

Comment: try `tag[]=Antique&tag[]=Malfunction`

Answer (score 0):

if you will provide your args like below it should work:

`http://localhost:8080/mybrocki/ads/filter?tag=Antique,Malfunction`

Comment: so the issue is that findAll() receives empty tags or getAdsByParam() receives empty tags?

Comment: I debbuged it, and from that side everything is okay I have list of tags which are in URl, maybe my foreach where I am iterating through every single tags from that list is wrong

Comment: ok, i thought that you have problem with mapping values from URL to a list in controller.

Comment: No, no I think my filtering is problem..:)